# is it possible to sort a serializeArray in .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, vb.net

I have data that I create using jQuery with JavaScript and save via ajax to  and then save it in a Ms SQL database in one field.

```
    var data = $('#frm').serializeArray();
```

The serializeArray creates the name value pairs.  It works well to save and retrieve but my question is if I want to write a html report in a .NET web service how can I sort by the from and to fields using either C# or VB.NET?  I could have 10 to 25 records that I would need to sort.

```
    [{"name":"Honor","value":"Good Award"},{"name":"Organization Name","value":"The City of Columbia"},{"name":"From","value":"10/01/2016"},{"name":"To","value":"11/01/2016"}]

    [{"name":"Honor","value":"Good Award"},{"name":"Organization Name","value":"The City of Charleston"},{"name":"From","value":"11/01/2017"},{"name":"To","value":"11/01/2017"}]
```

Should I think about saving the from and to separably?  Once I pull the records should I put it into a jagged array?  I could pull the records and make a .NET datatable then create a dataview and sort it that way before I put the data into an HTML table. Would that be slow? Any suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: This is just one suggestion of many. Use newtonsoft JSON to cast the JSON back into a dot net data class. Put the class into a list and sort the list as normal. Then serialize the data back out into JSON before sending to the ajax requester. Yes jagged array would work too. But if in the first place your data was stored in a table with fields for each property then you could have easily ORM'd it and Newtonsoft JSON'd it back to the web page.

Comment: If the records have already been saved in a database, can't you sort them in the same SQL query that you use to retrieve them from the DB? Alternatively, you could provide client-side (JS/jQuery) functionality to let the user sort the records by clicking on table column headers - if you know there are only 10 to 25 records the sort would seem instantaneous to the user.

Comment: The records are saved as a name-value array.  The array is currently the only field along with the form name. The sorting needs to be done on the server side since a report is created with the values in a chronological order.  But they could have been entered in any order.